# how to pass radiobutton selected object to struts2 action

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

here is my radio with iterator

```
<form action="<s:url action="s/postCreation"/>" method="post">
    <s:iterator value="categories">
        <s:radio name="myCategory" list="{Category}" listKey="DBId" listValue="title"/><br/>
    </s:iterator>
<s:submit>submit</s:submit>
```

where `categories` is an attribute in my struts Action class:(which has forwarded me to this jsp page) :

```
private List<Category> categories;
```

`listKey` and `listValue` contains values of my `Category` class which is :

```
public class Category  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Category.class);
    private long DBId;
    private String title;

}
```

now i want to be able to send the selected category object(and not just the DBId value) to `postCreation` struts2 action class and store it in an attribute named

```
private Category myCategory;
```

Answer (score 1):

No easy work-around.

I would solve this with a bit of JavaScript. Inside your `<form>....</form>`, I would write:

```
<s:hidden name="myCategory.title" id="hiddenTilteProperty" />  
<s:iterator value="Category">
    <input type="radio" 
       onClick="document.getElementById('hiddenTilteProperty').value = '<s:property value="title" />';"
       name="myCategory.DBId"
       value='<s:property value="DBId" />'
     />
<s:property value="title" /> <!-- This will act as label -->
<br/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: humm. let me test that and get back to u. thnx

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="yourActionName" method="post" namespace="/ifYouWantChangeNamespace">
```

Comment: what is that namespace? can you explain a bit plz

Comment: it doesnt post the Object, it is posting the id only

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to do here action="<s:url action="s/postCreation"/>".  method = post need not to method by default it's post. namespace - if you calling action is in another namespace you can specify here.

Comment: it is not about namespace , in "<s:url action="s/postCreation"/>" i am calling a struts action defined in struts.xml and using the s/ to avoid conflict with spring security calls

Comment: Do you mean you are calling an action postCreation which is located in /s namespace?

Comment: And can you provide what is the error message you are getting when you are trying to do that.

Comment: <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/s/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

Comment: there is no error message, post method just posts the string value, and not the whole object.